# How would I slice a value of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key, slice

hello I'm new to coding and I have to Define a function named filterByMonth with two parameters. The first argument passed to the function should be a list of dictionaries (the data), the second a number (representing a month, 1 through 12). This function must return a list of all the dictionaries from the input list whose 'issued' date is in the indicated month. 'slice' a string to more easily extract the relevant portion of a date from a string. Sample function call: filterByMonth(data,9)

With a list of dictionaries I need to slice the month which is a part of the value for the key 'issued' which is the third key in the dictionaries.

```
data = [ 
{'apno': 'FEND19-9487084', 'aptype': 'FENDRIVE', 'issued': '2019-09-05T00:00:00.000', 'stname': '129 PARKSIDE CT', 'city': 'BUFFALO', 'state': 'NY', 'zip': '14214', 'applicant': 'PETER CICERO', 'fees': '150', 'value': '3500', 'plans': '0', 'sbl': '0795300004001000', 'landuse': '411', 'inspector': 'ANDREW BLERSCH', 'expdate': '2020-03-05T00:00:00.000', 'descofwork': 'REMOVE EXISTING DRIVEWAY AND REPLACE IN KIND WITH CONCRETE TO CODE ON SOUTH /&nbsp;RIGHT SIDE OF STRUCTURE TO CODE&nbsp;- SURVEY SCANNED', 'location_1': {'latitude': '42.95116080935555', 'longitude': '-78.83406536395538', 'human_address': '{"address": "", "city": "", "state": "", "zip": ""}'}, 'latitude': '42.95116080935555', 'longitude': '-78.83406536395538', 'council_district': 'UNIVERSITY', 'police_district': 'District D', 'census': '45', 'census_block_group': '1', 'census_block': '1010', 'neighborhood': 'UNKNOWN', ':@computed_region_fk4y_hpmh': '5', ':@computed_region_eziv_p4ck': '64', ':@computed_region_tmcg_v66k': '8', ':@computed_region_kwzn_pe6v': '18', ':@computed_region_uh5x_q5mi': '88', ':@computed_region_dwzh_dtk5': '1573', ':@computed_region_b3rm_3c8a': '37', ':@computed_region_xbxg_7ifr': '24', ':@computed_region_urdz_b6n8': '7'},

{'apno': 'SWIM19-9485898', 'aptype': 'SWIM POOL', 'issued': '2019-08-19T00:00:00.000', 'stname': '341 NORWALK', 'city': 'BUFFALO', 'state': 'NY', 'zip': '14216', 'applicant': 'MS CHRISTINE SALAMONE', 'fees': '75', 'value': '500', 'plans': '0', 'sbl': '0785000006033000', 'landuse': '210', 'inspector': 'ANDREW BLERSCH', 'expdate': '2020-02-19T00:00:00.000', 'descofwork': 'INSTALLATION OF AN ABOVE GROUND SWIMMING POOL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; SUBMITTED THROUGH IDT', 'location_1': {'latitude': '42.95333872723409', 'longitude': '-78.85429233887896', 'human_address': '{"address": "", "city": "", "state": "", "zip": ""}'}, 'latitude': '42.95333872723409', 'longitude': '-78.85429233887896', 'council_district': 'DELAWARE', 'police_district': 'District D', 'census': '49', 'census_block_group': '1', 'census_block': '1000', 'neighborhood': 'UNKNOWN', ':@computed_region_fk4y_hpmh': '5', ':@computed_region_eziv_p4ck': '51', ':@computed_region_tmcg_v66k': '7', ':@computed_region_kwzn_pe6v': '5', ':@computed_region_uh5x_q5mi': '190', ':@computed_region_dwzh_dtk5': '944', ':@computed_region_b3rm_3c8a': '28', ':@computed_region_xbxg_7ifr': '25', ':@computed_region_urdz_b6n8': '2'},

]

def filterByMonth(dta,month):
  result=[]
  for x in dta:
    for y in x:
      for x['issued'] in y
        if month== x[6]:
          result.append(x)
  return result
print(filterByMonth(data,9))
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python string slicing tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a replacement for normal research.  When you make an honest attempt and post your code -- [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here -- *then* we're ready to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this more easily with the datetime module like so

```
from datetime import datetime

data = [
{'apno': 'FEND19-9487084', 'aptype': 'FENDRIVE', 'issued': '2019-09-05T00:00:00.000', 'stname': '129 PARKSIDE CT', 'city': 'BUFFALO', 'state': 'NY', 'zip': '14214', 'applicant': 'PETER CICERO', 'fees': '150', 'value': '3500', 'plans': '0', 'sbl': '0795300004001000', 'landuse': '411', 'inspector': 'ANDREW BLERSCH', 'expdate': '2020-03-05T00:00:00.000', 'descofwork': 'REMOVE EXISTING DRIVEWAY AND REPLACE IN KIND WITH CONCRETE TO CODE ON SOUTH /&nbsp;RIGHT SIDE OF STRUCTURE TO CODE&nbsp;- SURVEY SCANNED', 'location_1': {'latitude': '42.95116080935555', 'longitude': '-78.83406536395538', 'human_address': '{"address": "", "city": "", "state": "", "zip": ""}'}, 'latitude': '42.95116080935555', 'longitude': '-78.83406536395538', 'council_district': 'UNIVERSITY', 'police_district': 'District D', 'census': '45', 'census_block_group': '1', 'census_block': '1010', 'neighborhood': 'UNKNOWN', ':@computed_region_fk4y_hpmh': '5', ':@computed_region_eziv_p4ck': '64', ':@computed_region_tmcg_v66k': '8', ':@computed_region_kwzn_pe6v': '18', ':@computed_region_uh5x_q5mi': '88', ':@computed_region_dwzh_dtk5': '1573', ':@computed_region_b3rm_3c8a': '37', ':@computed_region_xbxg_7ifr': '24', ':@computed_region_urdz_b6n8': '7'},
{'apno': 'SWIM19-9485898', 'aptype': 'SWIM POOL', 'issued': '2019-08-19T00:00:00.000', 'stname': '341 NORWALK', 'city': 'BUFFALO', 'state': 'NY', 'zip': '14216', 'applicant': 'MS CHRISTINE SALAMONE', 'fees': '75', 'value': '500', 'plans': '0', 'sbl': '0785000006033000', 'landuse': '210', 'inspector': 'ANDREW BLERSCH', 'expdate': '2020-02-19T00:00:00.000', 'descofwork': 'INSTALLATION OF AN ABOVE GROUND SWIMMING POOL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; SUBMITTED THROUGH IDT', 'location_1': {'latitude': '42.95333872723409', 'longitude': '-78.85429233887896', 'human_address': '{"address": "", "city": "", "state": "", "zip": ""}'}, 'latitude': '42.95333872723409', 'longitude': '-78.85429233887896', 'council_district': 'DELAWARE', 'police_district': 'District D', 'census': '49', 'census_block_group': '1', 'census_block': '1000', 'neighborhood': 'UNKNOWN', ':@computed_region_fk4y_hpmh': '5', ':@computed_region_eziv_p4ck': '51', ':@computed_region_tmcg_v66k': '7', ':@computed_region_kwzn_pe6v': '5', ':@computed_region_uh5x_q5mi': '190', ':@computed_region_dwzh_dtk5': '944', ':@computed_region_b3rm_3c8a': '28', ':@computed_region_xbxg_7ifr': '25', ':@computed_region_urdz_b6n8': '2'}
]

def filterByMonth(data, month):
    result = []
    for item in data:
        datestring = item['issued']
        dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
        if dt.month == month:
            result.append(item)
    return result

print(filterByMonth(data, 9))
```

and a more pythonic way would be this

```
def filterByMonth(data, month):
    return [item for item in data if datetime.strptime(item['issued'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').month == month]
```

Comment: How did u get the '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'

Comment: You can read the strptime documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f

Year-month-dayTHour:Minute:Second.Millisecond